# How can I split out this list containing a dictionary into separate columns?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

The top table is what I have and the bottom is what I want. I'm doing this in a Pandas dataframe. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Is your `sentiment` column a list or a string representing a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would have been nice if you provided a code snippet for this since we are unable to easily test your case.

The following lines should do the job:

```py
df['label'] = df['sentiment'].apply(lambda x: x[0]['label'])
df['score'] = df['sentiment'].apply(lambda x: x[0]['score'])
```

Comment: Apologies, I tried to provide the tables in Mark down but stack overflow didn't like the formatting. I think it might have been something to do with the dictionaries within the lists!